# Custom Document -Like content type with Custom Item Parent

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm wanting to create a custom content type that inherits from Item. I then want to create a content type like 'Document' but have it inherit from my Custom Item content type. For clarity this is how the inheritance normally works: System -> Item -> Document -> My Custom Document

But I really want: System -> Item -> My Custom Item -> My Custom Document

Has anyone tried this before? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between **Item** and **Document** is that the content type **Document** has the Column **Name** (internal name: FileLeafRef).
But even if you manage to add the field to your *My Custom Item* content type it would still be considered an item content type as opposed to a document content type. It will not show up as a valid content type for document libraries.

Therefore my answer is: No, this is not possible.

You would have to build your *My Custom Document* to have the same site columns as *My Custom Item*, but inherit from **Document** instead of **Item**.